# Can you see me now.. What am I?

Tags: riddle

When few I can be invisible

As I breed I become more visible

A haze to conceal

I'm weird to feel

You've helped make me

What am I?

Hint:

> I'm dead

Hint 2:

> I like thing old

Hint 3:

> Sneeze

Comment: A dead thing that breeds? That's weird.

Comment: Is Hint #2 deliberately ungrammatical?

Comment: @Peregrine Took, no just hard to type on mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:

> Dust

When few I become invisible:

> You can't see dust if there isn't a lot of it

As I breed I become more visible:

> Dust accumulates over time and you can see it when there is enough.

A haze to conceal:

> When dust is on a surface or in the air, it looks hazy. And people try to get rid of it, the conceal part.

I'm weird to feel:

> Dust feels weird

You've helped make me:

> Dead skin cells are part of dust

Hints:

I'm dead:

> Dead skin cells are part of it, and it's not alive

I like thing old:

> Dust usually accumulates on old things

Sneeze:

> Dust makes you sneeze

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Mold/Mildew?

When few I can be invisible

> You hardly notice it at first

As I breed I become more visible

> Then there's more, and you notice it

A haze to conceal

> You don't want guests to notice mold

I'm weird to feel

> It feels kinda fuzzy

You've helped make me

> By getting things wet/Leaving food for too long

I'm not so sure how it fits with the hint though.

## Answer Two

> Germs

When few I can be invisible

> They're very small

As I breed I become more visible

> Ever notice a green stain on public water fountains?

A haze to conceal

> Germs everywhere, floating through the air...

I'm weird to feel

> ???

You've helped make me

> By 1.) leaving trash and stuff 2.) germicides and resistant little bacteria

Comment: I'll add a hint

Comment: Your heading the right direction, one more hint.  Might make it obvious

Comment: Your reasoning is great, it the answer